# Null Exception in Azure Mobile service channel

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-mobile-services, mpns, windows-phone-8

I am doing the push notification tutorial on windows phone. At start there is no problem with pushing the notifications.

However, after a few days I opened back the coding and got this error :

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=UtemFtmkDB
  StackTrace:
       at UtemFtmkDB.MainPage.ButtonSave_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
       at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.<OnMouseLeftButtonUp>b__3()
  InnerException:
```

In App.xaml.cs :

```
private void AcquirePushChannel()
{
    CurrentChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find("MyPushChannel");


    if (CurrentChannel == null)
    {
        CurrentChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel("MyPushChannel");
        CurrentChannel.Open();
        CurrentChannel.BindToShellTile();
    }


}
```

Whenever I retrieve data from `:App.CurrentChannel.ChannelUri.ToString()` I get this error. Why?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the channel hasn't reached the "Connected" status yet.

Check:

```
CurrentChannel.ConnectionStatus == ChannelConnectionStatus.Connected
```

Once that's true, you should have a non-null value for ChannelUri.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to hook up to the **ChannelUriUpdated** event:

```
private void AcquirePushChannel()
{
    CurrentChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find("MyPushChannel");

    if(null != CurrentChannel)
    {
        CurrentChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += CurrentChannelOnChannelUriUpdated;        
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel("MyPushChannel");
        CurrentChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += CurrentChannelOnChannelUriUpdated;        

        CurrentChannel.Open();
        CurrentChannel.BindToShellTile();
    }
}

private void CurrentChannelOnChannelUriUpdated(object sender, NotificationChannelUriEventArgs args)
{
    // you can now get the URI from args.ChannelUri
}
```

Note that the channel uri might also change for an existing channel. So you should listen for the ChannelUriUpdated event regardless of wheter you are creating a new channel or not.